# Predictions based on resistance measurements not matching reality?

Tags: resistance, amperage, electricity

I'm using my multimeter to measure the resistance of my tongue, and leaving it on there for a full minute it seems to average out at around 1.5 Million Ohms.

However, when I put a 9 volt battery on my tongue, I can definitely feel an unpleasant shock.

According to Ohm's Law, the current going through my tongue should only be (9 / 1.5M) = 0.000006 Amps (0.006 mA). However, [this chart](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/physics/p616/safety/fatal_current.gif) indicates that anything under 1 mA should be imperceptible.

Why can I feel the battery through my tongue?

Answer (score 0):

Your tongue is more sensitive to electrical current than your fingers. You might find the current is higher than 6uA too with the higher voltage (linearity is not guaranteed). Frankly 1.5M seems extremely high for a wet mucous membrane- more in the range of skin resistance. It will also vary with the spacing (and area) of the electrodes.

Edit: I tried it with a multimeter and got more like 50K.

You can put the multimeter in series with the battery and actually measure the current from the 9V battery directly. Add a 10K resistor or something like that to protect the meter.

Answer (score 0):

A 'resistor' made from metal film, or carbon, or conductive ink, or a length of wire, is a very simple beast, and you can expect a fairly constant resistance from it.

Your tongue has at least two conductive solution interfaces to the electrodes. Electrolytic cells are notorious for behaving in a very voltage sensitive way. As they're water-based, the dissociation voltage of water, around 1.7v, will be key. You can expect voltages below this to drive very little current through the cells, so they will appear high resistance. As the voltage increases above that, much more current will flow.

Comment: So the multimeter is using less than 9 volts to measure the resistance of my tongue and that's why it's inaccurate and why I don't feel it on the probes?

Comment: Borrow another meter to measure the voltage of the first one

Comment: If I ever get another multimeter I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

1. The resistance of your tongue is most certainly **not** 1.5  mega ohms.  My skin resistance is only in the 10s of kilo ohms, and it's dry as the sahara.
2. Your tongue has far more nerve endings than normal skin, making it more sensitive.

I can put a 9V battery on anyplace on my skin and not feel it.  I will **not** put a 9V battery on my tongue.

1.5V from a C cell is bad enough - and one end of it is only touching the skin of my hand rather than a second spot on my tongue. I **did** lick a 9V battery once when I was a little kid - ain't doing it again.

I expect you've done something wrong in measuring the resistance of your tongue.

Even just doing that must have been unpleasant.  Keeping contact with the probes for more than a second or so seems like it would be a really not fun thing to do.

Comment: How do you check your 9V batteries to see if they're dead then? Licking them is the traditional method in my circles. ;-)

Comment: Licking the 9 volt batteries gave a minor sensation, I wouldn't call it painful. Testing the resistance with the multimeter had no sensation at all...